# Can you remove specific grid lines and point labels using highcharts without css?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Currently I'm using css to remove my y-axis grid lines and labels like in the below image.

[image: nonexported-highchart]

CSS:

```
.highcharts-yaxis-grid path:nth-child(1),.highcharts-yaxis-grid path:nth-child(2),
.highcharts-yaxis-grid path:nth-child(4),.highcharts-yaxis-grid path:nth-child(5){ stroke:transparent !important; }
.highcharts-yaxis-labels text:nth-child(1),.highcharts-yaxis-labels text:nth-child(2),
.highcharts-yaxis-labels text:nth-child(4),.highcharts-yaxis-labels text:nth-child(5){ fill:transparent !important; }
```

Whenever I download the chart as an image they reappear which makes sense as it doesn't see the css file I'm using.

[image]

I've tried to search for an answer on highcharts or anything on the net and haven't had luck, so here I am presenting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in the `load` event you can remove specific `labels` and `gridLines`:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var chart = this,
                yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
                gridLines = yAxis.gridGroup.element.children,
                ticks = yAxis.ticks,
                tickPositions = yAxis.tickPositions;

            gridLines[2].remove();
            ticks[tickPositions[2]].label.element.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5m0s7th2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Nice solution! This managed to work for me. Also, this is important for everyone to know if using this method, but if you remove these array elements like 'gridLines[2].remove();' then you will have the index number change for the array. I'll show what I did in another answer using ppotaczek's method. Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the accepted answer I did this in a loop to avoid losing my middle gridline and tick val.

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        var chart = this,
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            gridLines = yAxis.gridGroup.element.children,
            ticks = yAxis.ticks,
            tickPositions = yAxis.tickPositions;
        var i = 4;
        while(i > -1){
            if(i !== 2){
                gridLines[i].remove();  // the whole array element is removed from gridLines, so we're doing this backwards
                ticks[tickPositions[i]].label.element.remove();
            }
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

It became a problem when I was starting from 0 using either the accepted answer or my loop. Hope this helps anyone who may have a ton of gridlines.